# how to remote add a single branch from a repository

Tags: git, branch, addition

Lets say we have an Assets project with *master* and *dev* branches
and another project named TheProject.

I want to remote add **only** the *dev* branch of Assets project.

If I wanted to add the whole Assets project I would do:

```
#Add a new remote URL pointing to the separate project that we're interested in
git remote add -f ASSETS git@example/assets.git

#Merge the Assets project into the local Git project
git merge -s ours --no-commit ASSETS/master

#Create a new directory called ASSETS, and copy the Git history of the Assets project into it
git read-tree --prefix=ASSETS/ -u ASSETS/master

#commit the changes to your master branch
git commit -m "Subtree merged in spoon-knife"

git push
```

But anyway thats not what I need. I thought something like:

```
git remote add -f ASSETS --single-branch dev git@example/assets.git
```

But if it worked I wouldnt be asking now! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code I posted does exaclty what I wanted..

```
git read-tree --prefix=ASSETS/ -u ASSETS/master
#adds only the master branch

git read-tree --prefix=ASSETS/ -u ASSETS/dev
#adds only the dev branch
```

So problem solved